# Positioning image in the center with inline href on left and right side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a picture in the center of the navbar and on the right and left links to other parts of the website. [How im trying to get it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKfVt.png). It works with position:absolute. Sadly the links stop working then. Any way to make the links work even with position:absolute. Or is there another way?

```css
  

     body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        
        }
        
        
         a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }
        
        a:hover{
            color: rgb(41, 171, 226);
        }
        
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        } 
        
        .image{
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 50%;
            display: inline-block;
        } 
        
        div{
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .navright{
            float: right;
              
        }
        
        .navleft{
            float: left;
            
        }
        
        .navleft01{
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .navright01{
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        nav{
            margin-top: 1%;
            margin: 0 10%;
        }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="image">
                        <a  href="#"><img src="images/place holder.png" alt="Placeholder" width="50" height="50"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navleft">
                    <ul class="navleft01">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">text1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">text2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">text3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="navright">
                    <ul class="navright01">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">text4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type="button">button</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: I'd assume this has to do with your `z-index` but yes we can't help you if you don't share a small reproducible example of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
let navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav__toggle");
let navWrapper = document.querySelector(".nav__wrapper");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (navWrapper.classList.contains("active")) {
    this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    this.setAttribute("aria-label", "menu");
    navWrapper.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    navWrapper.classList.add("active");
    this.setAttribute("aria-label", "close menu");
    this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap");
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2fa0f6;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button svg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: #fff;
}

.button span {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .button span {
    display: initial;
  }
}

.button--icon {
  min-width: initial;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


/* 
** The Header Media Queries **
** Tweak as per your needs **
*/

.brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.site-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #def7ff;
}

.site-header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .site-header__wrapper {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .site-header__wrapper>* {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .site-header__start {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .site-header__middle {
    order: -1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .site-header__end {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* Better for LTR/RTL support */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 659px) {
  .site-header__end {
    padding-right: 4rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 659px) {
  .nav__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #d9f0f7;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  .nav__wrapper.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.nav__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .nav__item a {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

.nav__toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 659px) {
  .nav__toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
  }
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block
}

body {
  line-height: 1
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Headers - 8</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="header-8.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header Start -->
  <header class="site-header">
    <div class="wrapper site-header__wrapper">
      <div class="site-header__start">
        <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="" alt="IMAGE"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="site-header__middle">
        <nav class="nav">
          <button class="nav__toggle" aria-expanded="false" type="button">
              menu
            </button>
          <ul class="nav__wrapper">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="site-header__end">
        <a href="#">Text4</a>
        <button style="margin-left: 10px;"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Header End -->

  <script src="header-8.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Would it be possible to do that without any js or librarys?

Answer (score 0):

I change your code by using `ul` and `li` tags, and I still just use HTML and CSS:

```css
/*body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}*/



.navigation-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  margin: auto;
}
/*.navigation-bar img{
float:center; //You don't need this because I write margin:auto in .navigation-bar
}*/
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.navigation-bar ul.left {float: left}
.navigation-bar ul.right {float: right}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
button{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <div class="navigation-bar">

      <ul class=left>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hCrQkJi.png">

      <ul class=right>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><button>Result</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't need `float:center` for the image this because I write margin:auto in .navigation-bar. I edit my code. thank you for the comment :). With `float:left`, `float:right` and `margin:auto` you reach it